# Selecting a Matrix Element in a List

Tags: r, list, matrix

Simple question using R:

I have created this list where i put a matrix 2x1:

```
a <- list()
a[[1]] <- matrix(c(1,35),nrow = 2)
```

The element a21 is 35.

How can i select this number and call it as `w`

```
  w<-a[2,1] , its not working.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `a[[1]][2, 1]` ?

Comment: Or by element since this one is easy. `a[[c(1, 2)]]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to first select the first element in the list, and then the 2,1 element in the matrix.
In other words
w=a[[1]][2, 1]

Not sure why you want to create a list first...